# Meaning of "sequentially compact"

Tags: general-topology

What does *sequentially compact* mean?

Comment: What's wrong with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact?

Answer (score 4):

A topological space is said to be sequentially compact if every sequence has a convergent subsequence. It is said to be compact if every open cover has a finite subcover.

In metric spaces, sequential compactness is equivalent to compactness.

Comment: Sequential compactness is defined for topological spaces in general, not just for metric spaces.

Comment: Looks good now.